# Determine if a string only contains characters from the seven bit alphabet(c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, filter, sms

I'm developing an sms application in c#. The service that I use to send a message only allows characters form the 7 bit alphabet. I'm looking for a way to check if a message only contains characters from this alphabet.

My first idea was to split the message into a character array and then loop these characters and compare them to the alphabet. But I bet there is a much better.

7 big alphabet:
http://www.dreamfabric.com/sms/default_alphabet.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a utility GSM Encoding class (it simply derives from the abstract System.Text.Encoding) defined here: [The GSM character set in .NET](http://www.mediaburst.co.uk/blog/the-gsm-character-set-in-net/). I think this is the most elegant and reusable way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to determine the encoding of input text look at the [Encoding class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)